# Karma + Webpack + Babel. Can't get Babel to transpile source or test files

Tags: webpack, karma-runner, babeljs, webpack-2

Trying to run simplest jasmine test written in ES6:

**Unit/page.test.js**

```
describe("test", function () {
    it("test", function () {
        [].find();
        // Object.assign(); // this fails as well
    });
});
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'Object.assign()') in page.test.js (line 145)
```

Looks like it doesn't know the new ES6 methods. I feel like polyfill is the missing part.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start"
  },
  "author": "eagor",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.16.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.5.3",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-babel-polyfill": "0.0.5",
    "karma-babel-preprocessor": "^6.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        basePath: "./Unit",
        files: [
            { pattern: '**/*.test.js', watched: false }
        ],
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        preprocessors: {
            '**/*.test.js': ['webpack']
        },
        webpack: {
            module: {
                loaders: [
                    { test: /\.js/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
                ]
            },
            // watch: true
        },
        webpackServer: {
            noInfo: true
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have somewhat the same problem here. I tried to open an issue on Webpack's repo [but it got shut down with no further notice](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5522). I managed to solve the problem by adding a `.babelrc` and it worked yesterday. Tonight, I don't touch the project a bit, my tests don't work anymore. There may be something wrong between Karma and Webpack.